# AWS CodeDeploy Issue: Cannot run hooks in appspec file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, aws-code-deploy, codeship

I have just started working with AWS. I am trying to deploy a nodejs application using codeship and AWS codedeploy. I am successful in deploying the application from codeship to Ec2 instance. But the problem is that I am not able to run the hooks file in appspec.yml. My appspec.yml is given below:

```
--- 
version: 0.0
os: linux
files: 
  - destination: /home/ec2-user/node-project
    source: /
hooks:  
ApplicationStart: 
  - location: bin/app-start.sh
    runas: root
    timeout: 100
```

In app-start.sh I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
npm install
```

The app-start.sh never works and node-modules are never installed. I have also tried to debug in the logs path(/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log) for code-deploy but there is no error and warning.I have also tried multiple things but nothing is working.

The project is successfully installed in Ec2 instance but appspec.yml never launches app-start.sh. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does Codedeploy say about the status of the deployment?

Comment: @Rodrigo In AWS management console code deploy says it says it is succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're moving the files to `/home/ec2-user/node-project`, which happens before your `app-start.sh` gets run at the `ApplicationStart` lifecycle hook. You need to `cd` into the right directory before running `npm install`.

Updated `ApplicationStart` scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user/node-project
npm install
# You'll need to start your application too.
npm start
```

As an aside, you may want to use the `AfterInstall` lifecycle hook to run `npm install` just for organization purposes, but it will have no functional different.